# Rubyでクラス変数の定義の仕方

Tags: ruby

クラス`C`でcase 1のような定義をすると特異クラスに
クラスインスタンス変数を定義できますが，
クラス`C2`でcase 2のように定義すると特異クラスに
クラス変数を定義できると思いましたが，以下の方法だとクラス`C2`に
クラス変数を定義していることが確認できました．

```
class C # case 1
  class << self
    @val = 100
  end
end

class C2 # case 2
  class << self
    @@val = 100
  end
end
```

確認したコマンド

```
2.1.5 :002 > C2.singleton_class.class_variables
 => [] # ここが[:@@val]になると思ったが違う！
2.1.5 :003 > C2.class_variables
 => [:@@val]
```

特異クラスにクラス変数を定義することは少ないかと思いますが，
なぜこのようになるのでしょうか

Answer (score 2, accepted):

特異クラスのclass式では、クラス変数に対するスコープを持てないようです。そのため、case 2の`@@val`は`class C2`内のスコープ、つまり、C2クラスのクラス変数として扱われます。

参考: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/doc/spec=2fvariables.html#class

> クラス変数は、その場所を囲むもっとも内側の(**特異クラスでない**) class 式 または module 式のボディをスコープとして持ちます。